# Set new missed calls as "old"

Tags: android

i want "reset" all missing calls, so far i did

```
public void resetMissingCalls() {
    Runnable reset = new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            Utils.PrintInfo("resetMissingCalls.run");
            String[] projection = { CallLog.Calls._ID,
                    CallLog.Calls.CACHED_NUMBER_LABEL, CallLog.Calls.TYPE };
            String where = CallLog.Calls.TYPE + "=" + CallLog.Calls.MISSED_TYPE
                    + " AND " + CallLog.Calls.NEW + "=1";
            Cursor c = getContentResolver().query(
                    CallLog.Calls.CONTENT_URI, projection, where, null, null);
            Utils.PrintInfo("CALLS " + c.getCount());

            c.moveToFirst();
            if (c.getCount() > 0) {
                do {
                    Utils.PrintInfo("coursor");
                    setAsRead(c.getString(c
                            .getColumnIndex(CallLog.Calls._ID)));
                } while (c.moveToNext());
            }
            c.close();
        }
    };
    new Handler().post(reset);
}

public void setAsRead(String id) {
    ArrayList<ContentProviderOperation> ops = new ArrayList<ContentProviderOperation>();

    // Number
    Builder builder = ContentProviderOperation
            .newUpdate(CallLog.Calls.CONTENT_URI);
    builder.withSelection(
            ContactsContract.Data.CONTACT_ID + "=?",
            new String[] {
                    id });
    builder.withValue(CallLog.Calls.NEW, "0");
    ops.add(builder.build());

    // Asking the Contact provider to create a new contact
    try {
        getContentResolver().applyBatch(ContactsContract.AUTHORITY, ops);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        Utils.PrintError("Exception: " + e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

however `getContentResolver().applyBatch(ContactsContract.AUTHORITY, ops);` throw an exception

*java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: URI: content://call_log/calls, calling user: com.test.missing calling package:com.test.missing*

i have both uses-permission

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CALL_LOG" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_CALL_LOG" />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i have fixed it by myself, just change setAsRead method to

```
public void setAsRead(String id) {      
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(CallLog.Calls.NEW, Integer.valueOf(0));

    String[] fv = new String[] { id };

    getContentResolver().update(CallLog.Calls.CONTENT_URI, values,
            CallLog.Calls._ID + "= ?", fv);
}
```